# Inverse of 2 by 2 matrix verification

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have worked our the solution to a problem, but I want to explain the solution in a mathematical way. I have the following matrix:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

And I get the following elementary matrices , call them E$_1$,E$_2$,E$_2$,E$_4$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I have verified that E$_4$E$_3$E$_2$E$_1$A=I$_n$

So I know that A$^-$=E$_4$E$_3$E$_2$E$_1$

Now if I want to write A as a product of elementary matrices, would I write it as A=(E$_4$E$_3$E$_2$E$_1$)$^-$ or do I have to write it in a form that has no inverse.

Comment: Your elementary matrices are wrong (well, all except $E_1$). You see, the elementary matrices you want are **not** the matrices you get on the RHS of the algorithm, these aren't even necessarily elementary matrices.

Comment: I redid them and I have verified that the above elementary matrices work. I have edited the question slightly.

Answer (score 1):

For example, on the right hand side, from $I$ to $E_1$, the row operation can be written as
$$\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}\\
A_1I &= E_1
\end{align*}$$
Where $A_1$ as a matrix transforms the rows of $I$ to $E_1$. Similarly the transform from $E_{i-1}$ to $E_i$ can be written as a matrix $A_i$.

---

Then if there were a series of row operations to the left hand side that transforms the left hand side to $I$:

$$A_n\cdots A_2\,A_1 \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} = I$$

Then $A_n\cdots A_2\,A_1$ is the inverse of $\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$. So on the right hand side:

$$A_n\cdots A_2\,A_1\,I = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$

Comment: I redid my matrices and have verified that they work. I have  included a new question in the last line. If I want to write A as a product of the elementary matrices, all I would do is take the inverse of each of them as shown above. And I would use the formula given for a 2 by 2 matrix. But I could have worked out the inverse of A using that formula 2, so what exactly was the take home message of this exercise?

Comment: @anna_xox which one is formula 2? Anyway, since $A^{-1} = E_4E_3E_2E_1$, then $A = E_1^{-1}E_2^{-1}E_3^{-1}E_4^{-1}$. And it is not too difficult to see that the inverse of an elementary operation is also an elementary operation.

Comment: sorry I meant too. Yes, the second question I had was that if I wanted to work out the inverse of E$_1$, I would just use the formula for inverse ,http://www.math.nyu.edu/~neylon/linalgfall04/project1/jja/inversion.jpg, but then I could have from the  beginning used that formula to work out A$^-$

Comment: @anna_xox It is easy to work out the inverse of an elementary row operation, but how do you plan to write $A$ as a series of elementary row operation from $I$?